# How to remove this circular dependency

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I am currently trying to design a piece of screen-capture software.

One design question I am having is **I want to know if it is possible to eliminate the circular dependency between the PictureGetter and the PictureProcessor.**

The getter needs to call the processor to tell it that a picture is ready. The processor has to tell the getter that it is done processing the picture.

These two elements are in separate threads and cannot share data directly(and I do not want to share data), they can only add member calls of the target object onto that object's queue queue. (eg `queue.add(&PictureProccessor::sendPicture,picture)` )

[image]

Comment: http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml

Comment: Yes, I know I can forward declare everything. This is a question about whether there is any way I can design around that.

Comment: Wow, seriously @themel??? RTFQ and you'll get the question.

Comment: Something generic, like the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?

Comment: Have you read this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Comment: @Pubby Yeah, I am using an eventfd(a file descriptor that acts like a semaphore)  to make sure that the reader waits if there are no messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a resource manager, make both aware of that. The getter can enqueue a picture to be processed with the manager, the manager can then have a "pool" of processors of which one can be used for processing. Processor can enqueue the processed picture with the resource manager which can then notify to the appropriate getter. I'm sure there's some funky name for this pattern, but cannot recall it right now.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for(and it also solves my picture management problem). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a 1 element queue from getter to processor.

Getter sends pic. Queue is empty when processor is done.